# Building boost without memory-mapped IO

Tags: gcc, boost, mingw-w64, jam

I'm trying to build boost 1.71 for a platform which doesn't have `mmap`/`munmap` (Nintendo Switch with devkitPro toolchain). The build fails because there is no `<sys/mman.h>` file.

How do I configure boost to disable memory-mapped IO? I have checked `boost/config/user.hpp` but there seems to be no relevant options in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Header-Only Use:

Make sure

- `BOOST_CONTEXT_USE_MAP_STACK` is **not** defined
- avoid including `context/posix/protected_fixedsize_stack.hpp`. (header guard `BOOST_CONTEXT_PROTECTED_FIXEDSIZE_H`)
- avoid including `coroutine/posix/protected_stack_allocator.hpp`. (header guard `BOOST_COROUTINES_PROTECTED_STACK_ALLOCATOR_H`)
- `BOOST_SPIRIT_FILEITERATOR_POSIX` is **not** defined if you use Spirit Classic
- Don't use Boost Interprocess shared memory/mapped files. `interprocess/anonymous_shared_memory.hpp`, `interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp`, `interprocess/mapped_region.hpp`)

  > There seems to potentially be a way to (de)configure some of the for BOost Interprocess but I don't know what sets `defined(BOOST_INTERPROCESS_POSIX_SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECTS)` and it looks like it doesn't cover all uses anyways

### For Library Compilation

The list is going to include all the above and anything that transitively depends on them.

> This could be a lot, but I haven't traced them. So maybe you are in luck for the libraries you are after

The following direct dependencies can be tweaked though:

- The copy of dlmalloc implementation embedded in Boost Container is configured to `LACKS_SYS_MMAN_H` already so no issue there
- Obviously `iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp` is a problem, so you can't build the Iostreams library (simply exclude it). If you need the rest, you can [follow their guide to include specific source files for specific parts of the library implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html#ide)

Comment: O shit - I did all my tracing on 1.74 until I noticed you mentioned 1.71. So, some details might be off

Comment: Not a problem at all. The lack of `mmap` is not my only problem, just the first one that popped up first, so I expect a few things to be off anyway.

Comment: A beginner's question: where is the right place to specify things such as `LACKS_SYS_MMAN_H`? Is there a syntax for such stuff in `project-config.jam`, or do I add them in `boost/config/user.hpp`, or in the compiler flags?

Comment: That's precisely the one example that is dlmalloc stuff [random repo doc link](https://github.com/rwaldron/runtime/blob/2396b5a0e1798875a1e37229809f086ca82fa64e/deps/dlmalloc/dlmalloc.h#L441). So there is no right place, it already exists in container/src/dlmalloc_2_8_6.c. Defining global defines is [a good question](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/config.html). I think I remember the docs being flimsy, but on that page you can find `define=`